# Vim syntax highlight file: how to match all occurrences of a character/symbol?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm learning how to create syntax highlight files.

My question is, how to highlight all the occurrences of a character/symbol say `=>`?

The only thing I know is that I have to do something with this:

```
:syntax match specialArrow
:highlight def link specialArrow Special
```

But I'm not very sure how.

Comment: +1 as I'd like to do this too!

Comment: This seems strikingly similar to your other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384785/how-to-highlight-the-symbol-in-my-coffee-vim-syntax-file

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, this works for me. Put this in your `.vimrc`

```
syn match specialArrow  "=>"
highlight link specialArrow     Special
```

You can verify this with `:verbose sy`

```
--- Syntax items ---
specialArrow   xxx match /=>/
                   links to Special
```

[image]